# Using cordova.file.dataDirectory and showing image in my app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I searched but I couldn't find an answer.

Im working with angular1 and using cordova.file.dataDirectory to transfer a lot of image files to my app, and allow to show these images offline.

The function to download the files seems to be working

```
var url = $rootScope.app.apiUrl+'assets/produtos/'+registro.arquivo;

var targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory +'assets/produtos/'+registro.arquivo;

$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function(result) {...
```

My problem is, I can't retrive this images to show in my app

Im trying to show them like this

```
var imagem = '/assets/produtos/' + produto.ws_codigo + '-1.jpg';
```

I know the file name is correct, but Im not sure if im using the correct path.

Im trying to use the dataDirectory because I dont want the images in android Gallery, or something like that.

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days I found it.

instead of

```
var imagem = '/assets/produtos/' + produto.ws_codigo + '-1.jpg';
```

i used

```
var imagem = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'assets/produtos/' + produto.arquivo;
imagem = window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imagem);
```

The result is something like this

```
http://localhost:8080/_file_/data/data/io.ionic.starter/files/assets/produtos/10078-0.jpg
```